# Generate file-directory-safe string using URL?

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, swift, nsfilemanager

My app is sent messages which sometimes include http links to images. When this happens, I want to cache the image locally, so I can display the image in future without needing to download it, if it exists locally.

But lets say the image url is `http://imgur.com/abcdef.jpg`. A file path of something like this, I'd imagine could have all sorts of issues:

`/var/Applications/[application]/documents/http://imgur.com/abcdef.jpg`

What I need is a way to take the given image URL and generate a file directory-friendly string, so that I can save the image using that URL every time, or check for its existence.

Comment: Can you be more  descriptive of what your string should be like? Is it just the image name? If so, you can use a regular expression to parse that out.

Comment: SDWebImage and NSURLCache both do disk caching so you might not even need to do this yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are many ways how to implement it (simpliest way would be to [create MD5](http://iosdevelopertips.com/core-services/create-md5-hash-from-nsstring-nsdata-or-file.html) of the web address, store image as [md5name.png] and then just try to check if md5 file reference exists), I suggest you use one of two libraries made for that:

- https://github.com/Haneke/Haneke
- https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

They both work on url-based principles, provide you with all known implementations of caching and they handle cases like this by default. Both of them also download images in background which is recommended way to do it and have convenience methods to load images in UIImageView.

Hope it helps!